# Can I marry an imaginary man?

Tags: zina, halal-haram

Both my parents work in a hospital. From a very young age, I've been left alone in my house for a few long hours till they come  back. During these lonely times, I imagine myself to be with people I've created inside my mind.

From age 7 to age 14.. till today.. from cartoon characters to more vivid imaginary people. I feel their presence, I have known them for years, I cry laugh smile for the events created inside my mind.

I do pray daily and have a very religious family. I live in Jeddah in a religious society. **I just need to make sure I am not committing any sin.**

Comment: How would you marry a person that doesn't exist? How would He ask for your hand? How would he accept marrying you and your guardian accepting him? This whole question sounds ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are joking around or not and I mean no disrespect if you are not joking around, but marrying an imaginary person is just a fantasy that is not reflective of reality. Many people fantasize as they don't like their real life. It is called escapism.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are trying to escape from the reality because you are alone, you may try finding a good friend, a good book, or a good online community. It is better for your mind to practice real action/reaction instead of fantasies.

Regarding imagining a husband, I would distinguish two separate thoughts.

1- Thoughts about life partner who understand you, loves you ...etc. and I have already answered this sort of fantasy in my introduction.

2- Thoughts about sexual acts. This is not permissible, even if you imagine him as your husband, because it will lead to haram.
**The Standing Committee for Issuing Fatwas** has been asked such question and they answered **It is not permissible for him/her, because it is an excuse to commit obscenity and to fall into evil and corruption**
[This is the source in arabic](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/137646/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%81%D9%83%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9-%D9%87%D9%84-%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%AE%D9%84-%D8%B6%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9%D8%8C)

Comment: Thoughts about sexual acts are not permissible, even if I'm a hundered percent sure that I WILL NOT commit them In real life?..

Comment: yes, they are unpermissible.

Comment: of course, they are not as the same sin as doing it in real.

Comment: So engaging in intimate thoughts about being with an IMAGINARY person, is a SIN?..

Comment: depending on 'intimate' meaning, the answer will be. If you mean pure LOVE, then the head of my answer is enough for you. However, if you mean SEX, then the tail of my answer is clear and answers your question

Comment: "Verily, Allah has pardoned my nation for what occurs within themselves, as long as they do not speak of it or act upon it.”
Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 6287, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 127
 .... I do not speak or act upon it ..so why is it still wrong?